# std::remove_if doesn't remove all items

Tags: c++, algorithm

In the input I would like to erase all non unique values. I want the subset after removing the double items to be identical to the input. Somehow some characters remain in the input and not all characters are removed. It seems like the std::map inside the predicate is also decrementing in size.

The predicate to std::remove_if() I am using is:

```
template<class T>
class RemovePredicate {

    public:

        RemovePredicate() : m_oldsize(0) {}

        bool operator()(const T& value)
        {
            //
            bool retval;
            m_uniques[value] ='a'; // 'a' could be any value
            cout << m_uniques.size() << endl;
            retval = m_uniques.size() == m_oldsize;
            m_oldsize = m_uniques.size();
            return retval;
        }

    private:

        std::map<T, char>   m_uniques;
        unsigned            m_oldsize;

};
```

I designed the predicate in such way that when I can see the size increases I have not encountered the input. So when the size is not the same I don't remove the input. When the size remains the same I've encountered that input value again, then I do remove it.

The code to test this is:

```
template<class T>
void print(T iterable)
{
    for (auto c : iterable)
        cout << c;
    cout << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (argc != 2)
        return 1;

    char * str= argv[1];

    vector <char> charvec (str, str + strlen(str));
    print(charvec);

    auto itend = std::remove_if(charvec.begin(),
                                charvec.end(),
                                RemovePredicate<char>()
                                );
    print(charvec);
    // apply erase remove idiom
    charvec.erase(itend, charvec.end()); 
    print(charvec);
    return 0;
}
```

a example input is:

> ./remove_duplicates deadbeef

output gives

> deabef

But as you can see there is still a double 'e' inside the output. But on the bright side the original ordering is maintained.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would use a `std::set<T>` in `RemovePredicate` instead of `std::map`. You can just check the return value from `set<T>::insert` to see whether the value you're inserting exists in the set already

Comment: @Steve Thanks that is a wellcome addition

Comment: @SteveLorimer: Or maybe even `unordered_set<T>`.

Comment: For this particular case, GCC's `remove_if` essentially calls `find_if` first to find the first element to be removed, passing a copy of the predicate, and then proceeds from there. Also, there's no guarantee that `remove_if` processes the input range in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no guarantee that every call to the predicate is made on the same copy of the function object.

You need to arrange for copies to share a single `map` (or `set` or `unordered_set`), e.g. by declaring the `map` at a wider scope and keeping a reference, or by using `shared_ptr` (so the function objects as a group still own it).

Comment: Or passing a `reference_wrapper<RemovePredicate>`.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Is this the case in many of the predicates in the c++ standard library? That you can't count on the members to exist  to remain valid accross multiple calls on a item in a collection?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: It's the case for all of them. The C++ standard explicitly notes in §25.1/10 that *"unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments are permitted to copy those function objects freely. Programmers for whom object identity is important should consider using a wrapper class that points to a noncopied implementation object such as `reference_wrapper<T>` (20.9.4), or some equivalent solution."*